# Implicit Riccati Equation Solver (to find the anti-stabilizing solution)

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra, undocumented, control-systems

I've found that the latest MATLAB [`icare()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/icare.html) solver includes the possibility to find also the anti-stabilizing solution of the Riccati equation.
I haven't found a similar option on Mathematica. Is there something undocumented or any alternative way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such option as of now.

But based on this [example](https://wolfram.com/xid/0cps5bgkads2aq-i2qow0) we can compute such a solution.

```
{a, b, q, r} = {{{3, 0}, {0, 3}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}};

{vals, vecs} = 
  Eigensystem[ArrayFlatten[{{a, -b.Inverse[r].Transpose[b]}, {-q, -Transpose[a]}}]];

unstableBasis = Extract[vecs, Position[vals, _?(#1 > 0 & ), {1}]];

{{x1, x2}} = Partition[unstableBasis, {2, 2}]; 

MatrixRank[x1] == 2

x = Simplify[x2.Inverse[x1]]

Simplify[ConjugateTranspose[a].x + x.a - x.b.Inverse[r].ConjugateTranspose[b].x + q]

(* True *) 

(* {{3 - Sqrt[10], 0}, {0, 3 - Sqrt[10]}} *)

(* {{0, 0}, {0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: Hi Suba! Thanks for answering. I would like to ask how you used Partition in this. Say my matrix system was sized n, would I have to use {n,n}? Also, it is unclear to me why you used {1} in Extract.

Comment: Yes, in general, we would use $\{n,n\}$. That is to partition the $n\ \times 2n$ matrix of eigenvalues into two $n\ \times n$ blocks. I used $\{1\}$ in [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) because it's default is $\{0, \infty\}$. In this case, `vals` is a vector so we can omit $\{1\}$.